# How do I switch to Bootstrap 4 in Laravel 5.5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

i want to switch to bootstrap 4 in laravel 5.5 ,

> i've run it before :

```
composer require laravelnews/laravel-twbs4
```

But I got a bad show in my "auth view" so i run tihs :

```
php artisan preset bootstrap4-auth
```

But I still have bad view in my auth view .
how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the below steps for installing bootstrap 4 in Laravel 5.5

To use Bootstrap 4 (BS4), which is in beta at the moment of writing, you will need to take the following steps:

- Run `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta --save-dev` to install/overwrite to the latest version
- Change `require('bootstrap-sass')` to `require('bootstrap')` in your `bootstrap.js` file
- Change

  ```
  @import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
  ```

  to

  ```
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  ```

  in your app.scss file. Also, make sure to remove the reference to variables since these will not work with BS4
- Run npm run dev in the command line to generate the .css and .js file

Please be aware that the scaffolded auth templates will break due to new class names in BS4, or you can follow this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-do-i-switch-to-bootstrap-4-in-laravel-55?page=1)

Comment: How can i run this npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta --save-dev ?

Comment: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. in command prompt , why ?

Comment: on which operating system you try this command linux/unix/windows?

Comment: I try this in Windows

Comment: Actually I'm not aware with windows too much sorry I can't help you in this situation.

Comment: i find out how to run it -- we need "GIT BASH" for windows (its a app)

Comment: okay great :) can you share the way you do that in comment i also have to know how you can do this.